# Accessing data from another table having one to many relationship in blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have one to many relationship of Product with Book.

Function in my controller:

```
public function editProduct($p_id)
{
   $books = Product::findOrFail($p_id);
   return view('master.editProduct')->with(['books'=>$books]);
}
```

editProduct.blade.php

```
<!--Returns Name from product table--> 
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Book Title</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value = "{{ $books->name }}">
</div>

<!--Should return author from books table-->
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Author</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="author" " value = "{{ $books->books->author  }}">
</div>
```

I also tried:

- `$books->books` which returned data of all column of books table for p_id
- `$books->books->author` to get only author from books table but returned error. i get error: Property [author] does not exist on this collection instance.
  How can i get the value of author from books table in my view?

Product Model

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
   protected $tables= "products";
   protected $primaryKey = 'product_id';
   public $incrementing = false;

   protected $fillable = ['product_id','product_type','name', ...,];

   protected $hidden =['created_at', 'updated_at'];

   public function books(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Book', 'product_id');
}
```

}

Book Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Book extends Model
{
  protected $tables= "books";

  protected $fillable = ['product_id','author', 'edition',...];

  protected $hidden =['created_at', 'updated_at'];

  public function products(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
  }

}
```

EditForm fields

- Title
- Author
- Publication
  .
  .
  .

Title is stored in Products table which i am able to access in my form as

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Book Title</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="name" value = "{{ $books->name }}">
</div>
```

In the same form author is not accessed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ProductsController

```
public function editProduct($p_id){
        $products = Product::with(['books'])->where('product_id', $p_id)->get();

        return view('master.editProduct', compact('products'));
    }
```

View
I used two foreach loops within my form to access name from product table and author from book table as follows:

```
@foreach($products as $product) 
  <form>
    ...
        <div class="form-group">
         <label>Book Title</label>
         <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" value = "{{ $product->name }}">
        </div>


       @foreach($product->books as $books)
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Author</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="author" name="author" " value = "{{ $books->author  }}">
          </div>
       @endforeach
  ...
  </form>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1):

Two queries solution:

```
$books = Product::find($p_id)->books()->get();
```

One query solution:

```
$books = Book::where('product_id', $p_id)->get();
```

To display data:

```
@foreach ($books as $book)
    {{ $book->name }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: i want to access name from product table and at the same time author from book table in my edit form. I am loosing $books->name when applying above. please suggest more.

Comment: @cnayak please show relationships and tables structure, so I could help you.

Comment: please look into the question once again. I have added more information.

Comment: @cnayak if you need author, just do `$book->author`. But if you also need to display product name, do this: `$product = Product::find($p_id); $books = $product->books()->get();` then pass both variables to the view and display data as `{{ product->name }}` and `{{ $book->name }}` inside foreach loop

Comment: it is not exactly what i wanted but i used the foreach loop from the concepts suggested by you and it worked for me. Thank you @Alexey Mezenin

Answer (score 0):

```
Model: Product.php
    public function books(){
        return $this->hasMany('App\Book');
    }

Model: book.php
    public function product(){
       return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
In controller:
    $books = Product::find($p_id)->books()->get();
In your view page
    @foreach ($books as $book)
        {{ $book->name }}
    @endforeach
```